# Flex: How to send the names/labels of selected items from a list to a php file

Tags: apache-flex

I know i can access multiply selected options of a list by

```
var selectedAlgos:Array = algosList.selectedItems;
```

where algosList is the name of my List.

How to i send this array via HTTPService to a phpfile and how can i then access the elements of this array from the php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn those items into a string using `algosList.selectedItems.join(",");`